# Handling my connection variable for login script use

Tags: php

Currently I am using

```
$con=mysqli_connect("x","x","x","x");
```

to handle my database connection on the login script. However, I'm trying to transition this to an OOP style approach such as

```
$con = new dbclass();
$con->openDB();`
```

I'm not having any luck with this though.

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 103

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 104

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 109

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 111
Acess denied, wrong username or password?
```

This is the method I'm using to do this.

```
function openDB() {

      $config = include("/assets/configs/db_config.php");
      $conn = mysqli_connect($config["host"] , $config["username"], $config["password"],$config["dbname"]);

// 1. Create a database connection
if (!$conn)
{
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
}
$this->conn = $conn;
return true;
}
```

Can anyone make any suggestions. Do I need to use mysqli_connect() somewhere within my method. Or even better, within my db_config file :

```
<?php
     return array("host"=>"x", "dbname"=>"x", "username"=>"x", "password"=>"x");


mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include()` does not cause the variables defined therein to become an array - they are automatically imported into the scope in which you are calling the function. Since you are not defining `$config` inside the include file, you're never accessing the array.

So, `$config = include('your_script.php')` doesn't do what you likely think it does.

You should update the function as follows (and change the array definition inside `db_config.php` to define `$host`, `$username`, `$password` and `$dbname`).

```
function openDB() 
{
     include("/assets/configs/db_config.php");
     $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // 1. Create a database connection
    if(!$conn)
    {
        $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
        return false;
    }
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return true;
}
```

That having been said, this isn't the best way to handle DB connections in an OOP application. If you need to move the config file, you have to update the `Database` class. It would be better to pass in the variables to your `openDB()` function as parameters, and then retrieve them from a config script in your controller somewhere.

For example, the following is much better practice:

```
function openDB($username, $password, $dbname, $host = 'localhost') 
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if(!$conn)
    {
        $this->error_msg = 'connection error could not connect to the database!';  
        return false;
    }
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I realise it's a bit late in the day, but I am unable to place an empty password object in my method openDB($name, $pass, $dbname, $host) password is empty so putting "", appears to not be acceptable. Is there any way around this? Thanks

Comment: Calling `openDB` as follows: `openDb('root', '', 'myDB');` should be sufficient and won't cause any problems...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this only initiate like $db = new db(); no need to open db it will already connect

**EDIT** 
here is code of db_config.php

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'bs_admin'; 



class db
{
  public $dbh;
  public $error;
  public $error_msg;


// Create a database connection for use by all functions in this class
function __construct() 
{
  require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config/db_config.php');
if($this->dbh = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)) 
{ 

  // Set every possible option to utf-8
  mysqli_query($this->dbh, 'SET NAMES "utf8"');
  mysqli_query($this->dbh, 'SET CHARACTER SET "utf8"');
  mysqli_query($this->dbh, 'SET character_set_results = "utf8",' .
    'character_set_client = "utf8", character_set_connection = "utf8",' .
    'character_set_database = "utf8", character_set_server = "utf8"');
} 
else 
{
  // Log an error if the connection fails
  $this->error = true;
  $this->error_msg = 'Unable to connect to DB';

}

// Add a row to any table
public function insert($table,$field_values) 
{
   $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' SET ' . $field_values; 
   mysqli_query($this->dbh,$query);       
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you just copied a generic PHP database class. This doesn't directly address the OP's question, since you failed to mention or post the code for `config/db_config.php`...